# Jquery function in a custom wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have created a custom wordpress page which is working fine, however i need to create a jquery function

I have created the function inside the custom page, but i am getting an error in the console when calling the function:

```
(index):232 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at LoadModal ((index):232)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):209)
```

Comment: your error says, that there isn't $ anywhere. replace in code you added $ with `jQuery`

Comment: or show your code to get full articulated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this line to the beginning of your script:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ is not a function` means that your jQuery library is not loaded. Make sure you include jQuery the correct way (for example in the `<head></head>` of your `index.html` file)

Comment: its in wordpress, so the jquery references are already in the site

Comment: @charlie `$ is not a function` means that you try to use `$` before jQuery was loaded (if it is loaded some time)